# How to convert a JSON object there in another object to string without any function

Tags: json

I want to post a json code to an API by **Postman chrome app** but as error that server gives to me one of values that is object, must be string e.g. lock at this json code:

```
 {
     "key1": "value",
     "key2": {
         "subkey1": {
             "subsubkey1": "value",
             "subsubkey2": "value"
         },
         "subkey2": "value",
     },
     "key3": "value" 
}
```

As you see value of `subkey1` is object, what I have to do **in the code** to its value be string?
**I don't want use any function or anything else**, I just want `subkey1` value in this code be string!
I used this:

```
 {
     "key1": "value",
     "key2": {
         "subkey1": '{
             "subsubkey1": "value",
             "subsubkey2": "value"
         }',
         "subkey2": "value",
     },
     "key3": "value" 
}
```

and this:

```
 {
     "key1": "value",
     "key2": {
         "subkey1": "{
             "subsubkey1": "value",
             "subsubkey2": "value"
         }",
         "subkey2": "value",
     },
     "key3": "value" 
}
```

but API gave me ***invalid json*** error!

Comment: Do you have this strict schema ? And do you ONLY want a check for value of the key in level 2 to be an object(json obj).

Comment: I will edit the question to be more explained.

Comment: "what I have to do in the code "...what code? You haven't even told us what language you're using to generate the JSON, never mind showed us the troublesome code. We'll need that before we can really help you

Comment: Anyway your last attempt is close but you need to escape the quote marks inside the string with backslashes ( \ )

Comment: sorry for that @ADyson ... I said those in the new edit, I have a json code and I want to Post it to a server by **Postman chrome app**, when I posted it as json in the app server give an error that one of objects that look likes `subkey1` in this json code must be string, I think I should do what you said about backslashes, may you use it in this json code to convert `subkey1` object to string please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last attempt is close, but you need to escape the inner quote marks so that they don't terminate the outer string. A backslash (`\`) is normally used for this purpose:

```
"subkey1": "{ 
  \"subsubkey1\": \"value\", 
  \"subsubkey2\": \"value\" 
}"
```

Comment: thanks for helping me...It worked right at the way I need